# 0.95-0.05 = 0.8999999999999999

Tags: javascript

Why in javascript `0.95-0.05` = 0.8999999999999999?
How can make = 0.90?

I discovered this into a complex app, but to reproduce it's possible to simply put the operation in the browser console.

Comment: Well, js is kinda especial with numbers, specially floating numbers. You can try `console.log(0.1 + 0.2)` to see what Im talking about haha

Comment: You could always move the decimal over, round, and move it back: `Math.round(((0.95 - 0.05) * 1e15)) / 1e15`; See: [example](https://pastebin.com/QJYb3JF9)

Comment: You have more information about this float behavior https://www.codemag.com/article/1811041/JavaScript-Corner-Math-and-the-Pitfalls-of-Floating-Point-Numbers

Comment: You can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: As a general rule, don't use vanilla JS math for anything that requires significant precision (It does the job 99% of the time, but you do not want it handling e.g. your banking software)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript, it's how floating point works in all languages that use IEEE 754 floating point, and that's pretty much all popular languages.